# IZPACK custom DataValidator unable to read custom panel user input

Tags: izpack

I have created a sample installer using IZPACK API. In this, i have created a custom panel class by extending IzPanel. After that i created a panel data validator by implementing DataValidator interface.

I have given its entry in install.xml as shown below:

```
<panel classname="TestInstallation" id ="TestInstallation"> 
<validator classname="com.izforge.izpack.panels.TestValidator"/> 
</panel>
```

Validator is running fine and showing error message. Here, I need to show error message depending upon wrong user input combination entered in panel multiple fields. But, i am unable to read user entered data in my custom data validator(TestValidator) and getting null. AutomatedInstallData.getAttribute("") as well as AutomatedInstallData.getVariable("") both methods are returning null in my custom data validator.

Please help and let me know if i am missing something here.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have you have your own validator by implementing the DataValidator intereface, you can get the user input from the InstallData object in your validateData overriden method. Eg.

```
@Override 
public Status validateData(InstallData data) {
  if (data.getVariables().get("MyFieldVariable");) {
     return Status.OK;
  } else {
     return Status.ERROR;
  }
}
```

"MyFieldVariable" is the name of the variable used in your custom panel. I guess you must have several input fields to validate against. But at least in this example it would be:

```
<field type="text" variable="MyFieldVariable">
   <spec txt="My own field to validate" id="MyFieldVariable" size="15" set="" />
</field>
```

For the error to be displayed an Status.ERROR is returned from  validateData(InstallData data) and you should override in your validator:

```
@Override
 public String getErrorMessageId() {
  return errorMsg;
}
```

This is available and tested with izpack 5.0.0-rc1. Mind that you should also then have the right maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-panel</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-rc1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.izpack</groupId>
    <artifactId>izpack-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-rc1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```